# How to all C++/WinRT from UMDF2

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, driver, c++-winrt, umdf

I develop an UMDF2.0 driver using VS2019.
Inside this driver I need to communicate with an BLE device.
I have to use [BluetoothLEDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice?view=winrt-22000) class to do this. This is a WinRT Api.
I'm completely lost on how to call C++/WinRT from my driver.
Does anyone have experienced this situation ?

Thank a lot for your great support,

## EDIT 1#

I use the following simple test code in new cpp file into umdf2 sample project:

```
#include <windows.devices.h>
#include <windows.devices.bluetooth.h>
#include <windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.h>
using namespace ABI::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth;

void testBle()
{
    BluetoothLEDevice dev;

}
```

I have the following error :

Error C2079
'dev' uses a class of 'ABI::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice' not defined

## EDIT 2

I found one usefull project on GitHub that help me a lot to make all this work. Please find the link below :

https://github.com/bucienator/ble-win-cpp

Thank you again for your help

Comment: In UMDF you can freely call any WinRT API as it is just a COM API. Or you can use any thrid party that incapsulates all the functions and provides simple access to the BLE features.

Comment: Hi @MikePetrichenko, Thank you for your answer. I think I miss something. I have a umdf2 template project. Do I need to configure someting specific in the parameter project ? Thanks a lot again

Comment: Nom you do not need something special. As I wrote WinRT API is a simple COM API. So you can call any WinRT API from your UMDF driver without any problem. (UMDF is also COM based, just FYI).

Comment: Thank you @MikePetrichenko. I'm new to driver development and i'm a little bit lost using theses technologies. I made new tests with umdf2 template but i'm not able to create BluetoothLEDevice... I add simple c++ source code to main thread. What do I miss ? Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: You should read something about WinRT usage in desktop applications first. Or, as I wrote early, you can simple use any third party libraries that incapsulates all the things. For C++ you can try Bluetooth Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate the BluetoothLEDevice with default constructor because there is no such constructor in this case.

Please use this code snippet in instantiate the BT device.

```
#include <winrt/windows.devices.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.h>

using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth;

void testBle()
{
    BluetoothLEDevice btDev = NULL;
    IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice> launchOp =    
    BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync(L"test");
    btDev = launchOp.GetResults();
}
```

Comment: Hi Prasanna K, Thank you for your feedback. I found one usefull project on Github that helped me to implement ble into my driver. I add the link inside my first post.